# Is there a sandbox for Google Directory API

Tags: google-admin-sdk

I want to develop an application that will be able to dial in to corporate clients' Google Apps Domain to get user info and groups. Is there a sandbox available where I can do this? Otherwise it looks like I would have to provision a (say) 200 user account and this could be expensive. Or do corporate clients get a staging environment where I could test this work? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no sandbox like this as far as I know. Partners and large customers will usually have test accounts for this type of work but I don't believe these are made available to the general public.

I'd recommend scaling down your tests to as few users as possible. Also, note that Groups do not cost anything to create. If you are going to have to do something like this yourself, make sure you select the flexplan to ensure you pay for only what you're actually using.

Another option would be to see about buying a Standard Google Apps account. Ensure all features you're working on are available for Standard accounts though. I don't know the market for them but I believe you can find accounts like this on Ebay for pretty cheap.

Comment: Thanks Mike. These are all good suggestions. I'll try and find out if one of the clients has and will give us access to a sandbox. One other thought I had would be to ask them to give me a set of JSON files that are responses to the queries we'll want.

Answer (score 0):

There is no sandbox, but

- you can create a free 30-day-trial Account. (https://www.google.com/work/apps/business/).
- if you have an existing Google Apps domain you can request a development domain via your reseller or Google Apps Partner.